# how to reshape elements in a list :ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
i = np.array( [ [0,1],[1,2] ] )
j = np.array( [ [2,1],[3,3] ] )
k = np.array( [ [2,1],[3,3] ] )
l = np.array( [ [2,1],[3,3] ] )
l1 = np.array( [ [2,1],[3,3] ] )
l2 = np.array( [ [2,1],[3,3] ] )
l3 = np.array( [ [2,1],[3,3] ] )
l4 = np.array( [ [2,1],[3,3] ] )

a = [i, j, k, l, l1, l2, l3, l4]
b = []
b.append(a)
b.append(np.array( [ [2,1],[3,3] ] ))
b.append(np.array( [ [2,1],[3,3] ] ))
b.append(np.array( [ [2,1],[3,3] ] ))
b.append(np.array( [ [2,1],[3,3] ] ))
b.append(np.array( [ [2,1],[3,3] ] ))
arr = np.array(b)
print np.shape(b)
c = np.reshape(arr, (13, 2 ,2))
print np.shape(c)
```

When I try this I get this error message:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

How do I reshape elements in a list.  I'm not able to get the `len()` of the array in a list to reshape it.

Comment: Where is the error - which line? And what do the prints show?

Answer (score 0):

When you print out your `arr` you will get something like this:

```
array([ [array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2]]), array([[2, 1],
       [3, 3]]), array([[2, 1],
       [3, 3]]), array([[2, 1],
       [3, 3]]), array([[2, 1],
       [3, 3]]), array([[2, 1],
       [3, 3]]), array([[2, 1],
       [3, 3]]), array([[2, 1],
       [3, 3]])],
       [[2 1]
 [3 3]], [[2 1]
 [3 3]], [[2 1]
 [3 3]], [[2 1]
 [3 3]],
       [[2 1]
 [3 3]]], dtype=object)
```

You might understand that this cannot be reshaped.  It is an np-array of `object`.  The entries therein happen to be np-arrays again.

But to have a reshapable entity you need to have an np-array of some fixed dimensions with a plain type (int, float, ...) in it.  Your building of your input (the `append()` calls) build something which cannot be reshaped.

I guess you might get what you want when you replace these lines:

```
b = []
b.append(a)
```

by this line:

```
b = a[:]
```

Then I can easily do this after the rest:

```
c = np.reshape(arr, (13, 2 ,2))
```

And `c` will be this:

```
array([[[0, 1],
        [1, 2]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 3]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 3]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 3]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 3]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 3]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 3]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 3]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 3]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 3]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 3]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 3]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 3]]])
```

Comment: i have added set of images to a list where sizes are below(1L, 281L, 500L)
(2L, 281L, 500L)
(3L,)
(4L,). first two images it will show the 3D array , but from 3rd image, it was showing as 1D . how to retrieve image data from list .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532232/python-to-create-ndarray-from-list-to-pass-to-svm-valueerror-setting-an-array

Comment: I don't see the connection between your comment and my answer, sorry.  Are you trying to ask a completely independent thing here?  Please open another question then.

Comment: please find the question raised at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532232/python-to-create-ndarray-from-list-to-pass-to-svm-valueerror-setting-an-array